# Limit of $a_n = \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Is there is clever way to find the limit of the sequence

$$a_n = \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}}$$

without using the "$e$ to $\ln$ trick?" I managed to find the limit of $\frac{1}{3}$ by the latter method but I was wondering if there is a quicker solution. I thought of using the Squeeze Theorem

$$\frac{1}{4^n}+\frac{1}{4^n} \leq \frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{4^n} \leq \frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{3^n}$$

but the limit of the nth root on the LHS and RSH tend to $\frac 14$ and $\frac 13$ respectively so I can't reach any conclusion for  the limit of $a_n$.

Comment: The second term decays exponentially faster than the first and becomes neglectible, hence $1/3$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\sqrt[\large n]{\frac1{3^n}+\frac1{4^n}}
=\frac13\sqrt[\large n]{1+\left(\frac34\right)^n}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $a,b\geq 0$. Show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}=\max(a,b).$$

Comment: You mean $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{a^n + b^n}$?

Comment: Of course. I corrected it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of squeezing was a good one,

$$\frac1{3^n}<\frac1{3^n}+\frac1{4^n}<\frac1{3^n}+\frac1{3^n}$$ and

$$\frac13<\sqrt[n]{\frac1{3^n}+\frac1{4^n}}<\frac{\sqrt[n]2}3.$$

Comment: Oh! How did I miss this! Brilliant!